# is it possible to get a dict of Lists in python?

Tags: python

I want to add lists into a dictionary variable in python.
is it possible to get a dict of Lists in python ?

Comment: well, have you tried?

Comment: Did you try it? Did you fail? What is\was your problem? Please [edit] your question and show us your attempt.

Comment: Which part do you not understand how to do? Creating a list? a dictionary? Using a list? a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you still need a key for dictionaries, e.g.:

```
d = {}
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
d['l1'] = l1  # Define your own key for 'l1' 
d['l2'] = l2  # Define your own key for 'l2'
```

Comment: Good. Its working. Thankyou..Michel

Comment: Good to hear ... welcome to StackOverflow ... upvote correct answers and confirm the 'best' answer.

Comment: @GopiKirupanithi: Actually... welcome to SO, but please read the **[faq]** beacause this is a Q&A site, so you'll need to ask specific questions based on problems (what actually you weren't able to do). This is why we usually like to see the code attempt in the question. If you want to contribute to this site you'll have to follow its guidelines otherwise you might be soon (automatically) blocked from asking again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
In [1]: mydict = {'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]}

In [2]: mydict['a']
Out[2]: [1, 2]

In [3]: mydict['b']
Out[3]: [3, 4]
```

`mydict` has two lists. Key `a` accesses list `[1, 2]` while key `b` access list `[3, 4]`.

Comment: Could you explain pls...

Comment: @GopiKirupanithi I copied and pasted some demo code using [ipython](http://ipython.org/) which I suggest you use as well since it will considerably speed you up your learning. Added some explanation.